# How to get the normal attribute after set position?

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals

I need some help.
I would like to know how to get the normal attribute after set position?
I need to rotate the objects to align them to an animated mesh.

[image: viewport]

[image: nodes setup]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Have you tried the [Capture Attribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/capture_attribute.html) node?

Comment: @quellenform I don't get it: where to capture in this case? I may miss something...

Answer (score 1):

Capture Attribute not work for me, but a good guy helped me and worked with this setup:[image]